# iOS splash screen crash on physical device .NET MAUI

Tags: xamarin.ios, maui

I have a .NET MAUI application which crashes quickly every time I load it on a physical device after the splash screen. I have no idea why this is happening and BrowserStack logs show absolutely nothing for me to work with.

I have tried turning `<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>` in my `.csproj` file but that has not worked either. Please see my project config below ad let me know if there is anything I can do. I am using a custom `Dev` configuration.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('ios'))">
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Dev|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
    <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    <CodesignProvision>202303_Development_Distribution</CodesignProvision>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution: Some Company (SomeTeamId)</CodesignKey>
    <MtouchEnableSGenConc>true</MtouchEnableSGenConc>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    <EnableSGenConc>True</EnableSGenConc>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here are my properties for another look. Thanks in advance I really need to fix this ASAP.

[image]
[image]

Comment: did it crash on debug, release or both? Are you initializing (or not) any package or dependency that might be causing the issue? Did you check the phone logs using xcode?

Comment: If you remove the splash screen, does the app start up without crashing? If you make a new Maui project, and add the splash screen to it, does it crash?

Comment: @FabriBertani how do I check the phone logs using xcode? And it crashes only on physical devices. debug is fine, release, test & dev are problematic

Comment: @steve connect your iphone to your mac, open xcode, the Window>Device and Simulators, select your phone in the iphone tab and click on View Device Logs, order by date, possibly you have to symbolicate the logs in order to read them.